# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 - refers specifically to word "mcmaster"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to enter information from a registration page I made in PHP/HTML. The relevant PDO code on the page is:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=assignment','admin', 'puppies');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO 
    `testusers` (`id`, `username`, `salt`, `passhash`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `gender`, `dob`, `email`, `phone`, `school`) 
    VALUES (NULL, :username, :salt, :passhash, :firstname, :lastname, :gender, :dob, :email, :phone, :school')");
        $stmt->bindValue(':username', $_POST['username']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':salt', uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
        $stmt->bindValue(':passhash', $_POST['password']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':firstname', $_POST['firstname']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lastname', $_POST['lastname']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':gender', $_POST['gender']);
        $dob = (string) $_POST['birthyear'] . (string) $_POST['birthmonth'] . (string) $_POST['birthday'];
        $stmt->bindValue(':dob', $dob);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $_POST['phone']);
        $stmt->bindValue(':school', $_POST['university']);
        $stmt->execute();
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

The full error I receive is:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''mcmaster'')' at line 2

For context, I have a drop-down menu where users can choose what school they go to. One of the values is "mcmaster." If I switch to a different value in the drop-down list, the error changes to match the value (queen's, ryerson etc.). In my database, the "school" column is encoded as 64 character VARCHAR.

```
<p>What university are you currently attending?</p>
<select name="university" name="university">
    <option value="mcmaster">McMaster University</option>
    <option value="queen's">Queen's University</option>
    <option value="ryerson">Ryerson University</option>
    <option value="uoft">University of Toronto</option>
    <option value="waterloo">University of Waterloo</option>
    <option value="western">Western University</option>
    <option value="york">York University</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have an errant extra single quote after `:school` in the `VALUES` list at `:school'`  Remove that and things should improve.